# opencv-python 4.8.1.78 - не хочет работать с русскими именами файлов в пути. Это както можно поправить?

Tags: python, opencv

Приветствую всех специалистов!
Подскажите пожалуйста:
При запуске ***read_qr_code("./QR/data/участок.png")***
вылетает ошибка, как видно беда с именем файла, может както надо конвертировать?

> [ WARN:0@0.671] global loadsave.cpp:248 cv::findDecoder imread_('**./QR/data/╤Г╤З╨░╤Б╤В╨╛╨║.png**'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
> error:  OpenCV(4.8.1) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\qrcode.cpp:31: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !img.empty() in function 'cv::checkQRInputImage'

```
# pip3 install opencv-python qrcode pyzbar numpy Pillow

import cv2
import os
import qrcode
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont

img_path = "./QR/data/участок.png"
# =========================================================================


def generate_qr_code(data, img_path):
    img = qrcode.make(data)
    img.save(img_path)

    qr = qrcode.QRCode(version=2, box_size=10, border=14)
    qr.add_data(data)
    qr.make()

    # print("The shape of the QR image:", np.array(qr.get_matrix()).shape)
    img = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color=(255, 95, 235))
    # добавляем надпись в изображение
    I1 = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    myFont = ImageFont.truetype('./QR/Roboto-Bold.ttf', size=60)
    I1.text((10, 10), data, font=myFont, fill=(0, 0, 0))  # текст из DATA

    img.save(img_path)

# ========================================================================
# DECODE QR-CODE
# ========================================================================


def read_qr_code(img_path):
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    detector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
    try:
        data, bbox, _ = detector.detectAndDecode(img)
    except Exception as e:
        print('error: ', e)
        return None
    # if there is a QR code
    if bbox is not None:
        print(f"QRCode data:\n{data}")
        return data

    else:
        print("QRCode not found")
        return None

# generate_qr_code("TESTisTEXT", "./QR/data/участок.png")
# read_qr_code("./QR/data/участок.png")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно через `open` который нормально работает с `Unicode`

```
import cv2
import numpy

file = open(u'C:\\Users\\Amgarak\\тест\\тест.jpeg', "rb")
bytes = bytearray(file.read())
numpyarray = numpy.asarray(bytes, dtype=numpy.uint8)
img = cv2.imdecode(numpyarray, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

cv2.imshow('Test', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!